# ¿Es posible asignar la posición de un gameObject en escena a una variable en Unity C# y usarla?

Tags: unity

Necesito asignar la posición del gameObject "Player" a una variable donde se guarde su posición y luego incrementarla, aquí un ejemplo:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class first_play : MonoBehaviour {

    //Creo que asi se guardaria la variable
    Transform posicion = gameObject.transform.position.x;

    void Start () {
        //Aumentara el valor x (horizontal) hasta que llegue a la posicion -500 de x
        while(posicion != 500){
            posicion++
        }
    }

    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La asignación de la variable se hace en el start, ya que se hayan iniciado los componentes, y el aumento lo haces en el update...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class first_play : MonoBehaviour {

   //Creo que asi se guardaria la variable
   Transform posicion;
   float velocidad = 1f;

   void Start () {
     posicion = gameObject.transform;
   }

   void Update () {
     if(posicion.position.x <= 500){
        posicion.position = new Vector3(posicion.position.x + (Time.deltaTime * velocidad), posicion.position.y, posicion.position.z);
   }

}
```

Comment: Gracias, solo necesitaba modificar el eje horizontal ya que trabajaba en entorno 2D, así que en lo de Y y Z le puse 0